# Как пробросить this во внешний контекст

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, асинхронность, promise

Вопрос находиться в комментариях к коду.

```
 export default class Abstract {
     construct(field = 'defaultField') {
      this.field = field;
    }

    method() {

     const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve('newField');
     });

     promise.then(
      (newField) => { this.field = newField; }
     );
     console.log(this.field); // defaultField - Почему? И как изменить this.field на newField?

// Получается я устанавливаю поле this.field для функции then?
    }
    }
```

Comment: потому что вывод в консоль синхронно вызывается. То бишь, рановато.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `console.log` — синхронная функция, а Promise — асинхронный. Вот и получается, что `console.log` показывает тебе `this.field` раньше, чем он успевает изменить своё значение

Пробуй так проверить сам:

```
// ...

method() {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('newField');
    })

    promise.then(newField => {
        this.field = newField

        console.log(this.field)
    )
}
```

Comment: этот код сам по себе не развеивает сомнений автора, что this.field внутри then указывает куда-то не туда. Простой setTimeout - куда надёжнее.

Comment: Ок! Я просто до конца не понимал механизм работы помисов. Теперь вроде все понятно. Спасибо!