# Как из асинхронной функции изменить значение находящееся во внешнем окружении?

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

```
export default class Abstract {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name || 'defaultName';
  }

  changeName() {

      fs.readFile('/somefile.wtf', (err, data) => {
       this.name = data; // не сработает
      });

}
```

Comment: объяснение абсолютно непонятно, можешь попробовать добавить поясняющий код. Пока закрою как дубликат вопроса про потерю контекста

Comment: а чем текущий вопрос отличается от предыдущего: [Как пробросить this во внешний контекст](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/626333/186999)?

Comment: А описание зачем убрал? Теперь у тебя один блок кода, в котором что-то не работает, а что именно не работает и почему ты думаешь, что не работает - непонятно

Comment: К тому же в приведенном примере - все как раз работает, так как ты и хотел. Все зависит от того как и где будет вызываться _changeName_. В прочем, об этом как раз и рассказывается в дубликате.

Comment: На первый взгляд ничем. Но там мне стало понятно, что Promise просто выравнивает код что бы избежать callback hall, но моя проблема фактически не решилась. Я соглашусь что не стоило ставить  точку в прошлом обсуждении и открывать новое. Но как мне тогда правильно получит помощь в которой я нуждаюсь сейчас?

Comment: Посмотри варианты в дубликате: определи место где у тебя теряется контекст, и исправь его

Comment: @Grundy ответ на вопрос нашел в дубликате. Спасибо!